# Implementing IOperationBehavior as an attribute

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a wcf service where my interface looks something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    [AllowedFileExtension]
    void SaveFile(string fileName);
}
```

My goal is to inspect the incoming message to verify the fileName. So my AllowedFileExtensionAttribute class looks like this:

```
 public class AllowedFileExtensionsAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
 {
        private readonly string _callingMethodName;
        private readonly string[] _allowedFileExtension;

        public AllowedFileExtensionsAttribute([CallerMemberName]string callingMethodName = null)
        {
            _callingMethodName = callingMethodName;
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {

        }

        public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {

        }
}
```

Invoking this from for instance WCF Test Client or a simple console application, my Attribute class is not invoked, it goes directly to the implmentation. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What I did is in `ApplyDispatchBehavior` I added an `IParameterInspector` to the `dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors` and implemented interception in the `AfterCall` and `BeforeCall`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WCF [**MessageInspector**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) to intercept the request and do whatever you wish to do.

> A message inspector is an extensibility object that can be used in the service model's client runtime and dispatch runtime programmatically or through configuration and that can inspect and alter messages after they are received or before they are sent.

You can implement both `IDispatchMessageInspector` and `IClientMessageInspector` interfaces. Read the incoming data in the `AfterReceiveRequest`, store it in a threadstatic variable, and if required use it in `BeforeSendRequest`.

`AfterReceiveRequest` is invoked by the dispatcher when a message has been received in pipeline.You can manipulate this request which has been passed as reference parameter.

See the [**msdn doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors).

```
public class SimpleEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(
            new SimpleMessageInspector()
            );
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    { 
    }
    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}



public class SimpleMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector, IDispatchMessageInspector    
{
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)    
        {
        }     

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)    
        {    

            //modify the request send from client(only customize message body)

            request = TransformMessage2(request);

            //you can modify the entire message via following function

            //request = TransformMessage(request);    

            return null;    
        }   

}
```

Check [**this post**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stcheng/2009/02/21/wcfhow-to-inspect-and-modify-wcf-message-via-custom-messageinspector/) for details.